# Auto timedate persistence with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am trying to save timedate to mysql using hibernate sessions but i am unable to do so.
I have a test class and I also created entity listener class for persistence but nothing seems to working

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(TestListener.class)
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time_date", nullable = false)
    private Date TimeDate;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getTimeDate() {
        return TimeDate;
    }

    @PrePersist

    public void setTimeDate(Date TimeDate) {
        this.TimeDate = new Date();
    }
    }
```

and my listner class is:

```
public class TestListener {

 @PrePersist
  public void setTimeDate(Test o) {
        o.setTimeDate( new Date() );
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the code persisting the entity?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Post your exact problem